# How to reveal unmask a series of object using animation keyframes or nodes

Tags: animation, masking, boolean-modifier

I have a set of traffic lights, Which I'm using a Boolean method to unmask/Reveal as I move my Boolean mask up and down the Z axis. I have also keyframed my Boolean so each traffic light gets unrevealed as I move one frame forward.

Is there another quicker or more intuitive method for this? The reason I'm asking is, I have 3 colour lights I'm revealing, but if I need to do 20 or 30 lights, it's a tedious task to keyframe the Boolean mask. So can it be done using Geo Nodes, or some other technique someone can share with me?

[image]

File included:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

This method is a lot faster than yours because it doesn't use boolean operations which are very slow in Blender.

Comment: Hi Chris, is it possible this method can be used in Vertical direction, for example, if I have 20 spheres Bottom-Top to be revealed one by one? This image is only for a demo. (Can be any shape) Imagine if each light opens up as its revealed. 

https://i5.walmartimages.com/seo/Monster-LED-Sound-Reactive-Rechargeable-Multi-Color-Color-Flow-LED-Equalizer-Light-Bar-Livingroom_26703779-ab77-492a-947c-a1e3fa1979b8.fae2ca83c0b7c3a4850213437e03fe52.jpeg

Comment: if you have just one object with 20 mesh islands it should work

Comment: Thank you Chris!

Comment: you are welcome